# 3rd Highest salary in Pig

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

How to get 3rd highest salary in pig even if it contains duplicates.

Please help me on this.

Input:

```
Sri 30000
Abhi 15000
SAS 15000
mansa 18000
asdf 5262
dnaj 20000
harda 20000
```

Comment: What is your desired result? You say even with duplicates, but you don't explain how you want to handle them.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this using RANK and getting the 3rd ranked record in the distinct salary relation.I'll use LIMIT.

```
A = LOAD 'data.txt' USING PigStorage('\t') AS (name:chararray,salary:int);
B = FOREACH A GENERATE A.Salary;
C = DISTINCT B;
D = ORDER C BY C.$0 DESC;
E = LIMIT D 3;
F = ORDER E BY E.$0 ASC;
G = LIMIT F 1;
H = FILTER A BY (A.Salary = G.$0);
```

**A**

```
Sri 30000
Abhi 15000
SAS 15000
mansa 18000
asdf 5262
dnaj 20000
harda 20000
```

**B**

```
30000
15000
15000
18000
5262
20000
20000
```

**C**

```
30000
15000
18000
5262
20000
```

**D**

```
30000
20000
18000
15000
5262
```

**E**

```
30000
20000
18000
```

**F**

```
18000
20000
30000
```

**G**

```
18000
```

**H**

```
mansa 18000
```